# encryption tokenization for credit card

Tags: format-preserving

I have put in place a solution for a cryptographic tokenization engine for credit-card numbers.
You can find it under the following [repository](https://github.com/rbroggi/crypto-token). In the implementation I tried to respect some requirements that actually weakens the final solution, specially:

1. 6x4 digit credit-card digit preserving
2. token need to maintain the credit-card length

Those restrictions leave me with a rather small domain/image for my encryption algorithm. Nevertheless I would like to ask for your view/toughts around the weaknesses/strengths/vulnerabilities of this approach.

So in terms of threat model I would be particularly interested in a scenario where an attacker would have access to the 'tokenization' engine and therefore he would be able to generate tokens from credit cards and with that create a table [CC -> TK] (where CC stands for credit cards and TK stands for Tokens).
With that possibility at hand, and considering the attacker has a table [CC -> TK] is there a procedure in which he could raise considerably the possibility to 'decrypt' a token that is not in the table? Is there a strategy for the attacker to enhance his probability of relating any given token to a credit-card by choosing the right set of CCs to inject?
Knowing that if the attacker maps every possible CC to TK, the encryption would be broken, and considering that this is a computationally unfeasible task, how could the attacker gain most insight on the tokens with a limited set of injections?

Moderator note: FF1 is a format-preserving encryption mode specified in [NIST SP 800-38G](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-38G.pdf). A [later draft](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-38Gr1-draft.pdf) has stricter parameters for FF1.

Comment: Are you asking about your specific approach? Or about the inherent weaknesses caused by preserving format? It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish? Are you hashing/encrypting? What is your threat model?

Comment: I second that the question requires a better statement of goals. Also, it's needed a description of how FF1 is used, in the question itself, in order to make the question really [on-topic](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).